# How to MOC the Rough Terrain Crane 42082

Tags: technic, moc

I recently got me the Rough Terrain Crane 42082 and had lots of fun while assembling it. I find it a decent Technic build and worth the price. Still I find it under-motorized. I would like to drive and steer it. Do you know where I could find MOC instructions to modify and motorize the crane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are building instructions in this video of a fully motorized version: https://youtu.be/mmKw_GBFGs0

And here is a demonstration by the same builder how it all works: https://youtu.be/RzBaDTpG2Ss